# ordering matrix by vector correctly

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I don't understand why I cannot order a matrix based on a vector using the *order* function

I have the following:

```
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    5
[4,]    4    5
[5,]    5    5
[6,]    6    5

v
[[1]]
[1] 3 1 2 4 5 6
```

When I use:

```
m[order(unlist(v)),]
```

I get the following, incorrectly ordered matrix.

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    5
[2,]    3    5
[3,]    1    5
[4,]    4    5
[5,]    5    5
[6,]    6    5
```

when the order that I want is what's in *v*

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    1    5
[3,]    2    5
[4,]    4    5
[5,]    5    5
[6,]    6    5
```

Why do you guys think this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: um.... `m[unlist(v),]`?

Comment: thanks, but my question is why can't you use order in this case?

Comment: @user3141121 Look at `unlist(v)[order(unlist(v))]`. It it ordering the vector, but order returns the permutations of the indexes that results in a sorted order. As Simon pointed out, if you want to explicitly give the indexes, then don't use `order()`.

Comment: Well, read the help page: `?order`, then try `order(unlist(v))` and `unlist(v)[ order(unlist(v))]` and see if you can work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
m[order(unlist(v)),]
```

Try

```
temp <- unlist(v)
m[ temp , ]
```

Because `order` returns the *indexes* in the order that you desire. E.g.

```
> x = c(3,1,2)
> order(x)
[1] 2 3 1
> x[order(x)]
[1] 1 2 3
```